# How can you activate a piston array from below?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm looking to make a large round table which would come up from the floor when activated by pistons.

I've attached an image to show exactly what I'm doing. I've tried putting blocks underneath attached to my red stone torch and wiring it up but I cant get to the middle blocks. It would be nice to find one method that can be laid out and activated so that the blocks above are activated.

Hope that makes sense!

[image: Showing the array of the table]

[image: This shows the simplistic array I hope to achieve.]

Comment: You could use redstone blocks pushed up from below using pistons... Oh, wait... :P

Answer (score 13):

You have to do it in three dimensions, with multiple layers. You need one layer of circuitry for each ring of the table. Since you have a table that has three rings, you need three sets of circuits that generate the right signal in the right pattern. Each ring after the first needs to be down a layer so there's room to do the wiring, and then you have to carry the signal upward with vertical redstone torch connections.

This is an overview shot of a working implementation that I just made:

[image: Overview of a three-ring piston table and some of its wiring]

And here's a long view of the wiring layers:

[image: Wiring for a 3-ring piston table]

The first set of torches are the activation torches for the pistons. (These are actually redundant*.) Each ring of torches is toggled *on* by wiring, so they have torches below them to keep them off until the switch is thrown.

The second set of torches from the top are part of the out ring's circuitry. The repeater ring around the second layer of torches turns them *off*, which turns the redstone torches in the layer above *on*, which activates the outer ring of pistons. The repeaters are hooked up directly to the main switch.

(Each layer of redstone torches also contains torches for the inner rings, because those are the connections that will let us bring the signal up from the lower circuits.)

[image: Outer ring wiring and top layer activation torches]

The next layer of redstone torches for the second ring's pistons aren't visible, because they're behind the blocks of the repeaters for the outer ring. You can see the repeaters that turn them on though. These repeaters are hooked up to an inverter from the main switch, because they need to be *off* to turn this layer's redstone torches *on* to turn the next layer *off* to turn the top layer *on* to activate the second ring of pistons.

You can see the layer's torches better up close though:

[image: Second ring wiring]

The last layer of redstone torches you also can't see, because they're again behind the blocks that support the repeaters of the layer above. You can see the third ring's repeaters at the bottom though. These turn the four middle redstone torches off, so that the next layer is on, etc., to make the top middle four redstone torches turn on to activate the four middle pistons.

Again, you can see the torches if you get up close and look under the supporting blocks:

[image: Third ring wiring]

* You can make a slightly more compact version of this if you get rid of the top layer of torches and invert the signal from the switch (or just be OK with the switch flipping the "wrong" way to turn it on.) That top layer of torches are redundant, and just left over from my experimenting. Unfortunately, I can't think of any way to eliminate any more of the vertical wiring, because the wiring for each ring has to be on a separate layer, and you need the room to move the signal upward through multiple vertical redstone inverters.

This is what it looks like from the side when the redundant layer is removed:

[image: More compact version without the redundant inverter layer.]

I've uploaded [the save for the compact version of the piston table](http://d7.pipemaze.com/files/piston-table.7z) if you want to get a better look at it.

Comment: Nice one! I made an own implementation myself, wich only requires 7 layers vertically instead of your 10 (including the floor with the pistons and the stones where your bottom redstone rests on). I'll post it in a minute.

Comment: Thanks guys this was very helpful! It made sense after I got into it and I even added 1 more ring. Cant seem to share pictures on this comment, brand new to the site so maybe im just ignorant on how haha. Anyway I wanted to say thank yoU!!!

Comment: @David Glad to help! That's one advantage of my less-compact solution, as it's extensible outwards. If you found an answer useful, you can mark it with the checkmark to show what you think the best answer is. (As for pictures: you can't in comments. Comments are deliberately made less useful so that we're not encouraged to abuse them for chat or extra answers. We're very focused on just questions, and just answers! Though there's [chat] for other stuff.)

Comment: Quite pretty... Would you mind uploading the gamesave?

Comment: @TomášZato I've added a link at the end of the answer!

Answer (score 4):

My method is a bit more compact vertically, but is considerably less elegant than SevenSidedDie's solution.

**Inside**:
[image: Piston Array wiring inside]
**Outside**:
[image: Piston Array wiring outside]
**Crosssection diagram**:
[image: Piston Array wiring crosssection]

The timing of the various pistons may need some work, and might require some expansion of the wiring to account for additional repeaters if getting everything to fire at (near) the same time is more preferable than not.

Comment: Nice! I like the circuitry diagrams in the last screenshot.

Comment: This was also my solution, but it was a bigger mess. It is possible to make them all fire at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a different sort of redstone pattern for this problem. Most of the other answers here use rings, so that the center gets deeper, and redstone has to be laid out in three-dimensional structures. This design:

- fits entirely underneath the pistons being controlled, so can be tiled to handle an arbitrarily-shaped field of pistons, and
- uses only 1 repeater (total 26 redstone dust) per 10 pistons, or two repeaters (28 dust) if you want complete synchronization.

Here I've built it with two copies left and right and only one layer deep, except for the bottom signal feed so that you can see how to hook it up.

[image: (screenshot)]

If you want to make it more than 14 or so deep, you'll have to feed the bottom from alternating sides to have room to repeat the input signal — but there's plenty of room to do that.

(This is a refinement of an old design I used on [a piston pool a few years ago back when that was a thing](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/kqunj/i_made_an_oasis/); but it was less efficient than this because it only branched once and had to go ever deeper as it got wider.)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the images, thanks again everyone!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: nononon, this is place for answers...

Comment: @Roberts This *is* an answer.

Comment: Yes, but this isn't your idea! You should accept SevenSidedDie's answer!